# How do I kill a playloop when a thread is killed?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, audio

Meet Thread:

```
    public void TimerFunc(){
        ...
        while (true)
        {
  ...
                sound.PlayLooping();
                // Displays the MessageBox and waits for user input
                MessageBox.Show(message, caption, buttons);
                // End the sound loop
                sound.Stop();
 ...

        }
    }
```

Thread gets started by a button in the main interface, and can get killed by a button in the interface.

How do i get the soundloop to stop if the thread gets killed when waiting for user input?

Comment: Look at Backgoundworker, this is much easier if you only need the thread for responsive UI

Comment: How are you "killing" the thread? If you're using a nongraceful abort, then, well, don't. Interrupt it gracefully and catch that exception on blocking operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You DO NOT kill the thread. If the thread is killed, it can't do anything.

Just politely send a message to the thread, asking it to stop playing.

```
private volatile bool canContinue = true;

public void TimerFunc(){
    ...
    while (true && canContinue)
    {
        ...
        sound.PlayLooping();
        // Displays the MessageBox and waits for user input
        MessageBox.Show(message, caption, buttons);
        // End the sound loop
        sound.Stop();
        ...
    }
}

public void StopPolitely()
{
    canContinue = false;
}
```

The button on the main interface will then just call `thread.StopPolitely()` and terminate the thread in a clean way.
If you want it to terminate faster, you may consider other and more aggressive solutions, such as checking `canContinue` more often, or using `Thread.Interrupt()` to wake the thread even if it's busy in a blocking call (but then you have to manage the interrupt)
Since it's just a bool, and it's single-writer/single-reader, you can even avoid declaring it as `volatile`, even though you should.

Comment: I'd like to be able to stop the sound and maybe even 'destroy' the MessageBox when that button is clicked, if that is possible. If not, i'll surely use this as it does solve the problem. btw, while(true&&canContinue)? why not while(canContinue)?

Comment: It was just to make it clearer that it should be and-ed with your previous condition. I just added to your code, without removing anything. Of course it's dumb.

Comment: I'm afraid destroying the MessageBox is a bit harder, because the framework gives you no handle to the dialog window. You can do it if you implement a custom dialog frame, which you use as a dialog box.