# How to run a Thread for a user specified amount of time?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice

Am creating a program that is based on mixing and making perturbation in a population containing solutions `Vector`.

**So I created a `for loop` that stops after a certain time given by the user.** 
Inside the loop, am going to call 5 procedures and I thought that if i put each procedure in a thread will make the program making more solutions in a same time than calling normal methods.

Here 5 created the 5 threads, but when i start them the don't want to stop even if i use the `Thread.stop`, `Thread.suspend`, `Thread.interrupt` or `Thread.destroy`

Here is my code and could u help me with your ideas ?

I have inserted a new variable :

```
public volatile boolean CrossOpb = true;`
```

Here is my code:

```
Thread CrossOp = new Thread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
   while(CrossOpb == true){
    int rdmCross2=(int) (Math.random() * allPopulation.size())  ; // Crossover 1st vector
    int rdmCross1=(int) (Math.random() * allPopulation.size())  ;
    Vector muted = new Vector();
    Vector copy = copi((Vector) allPopulation.get(rdmCross2));
    Vector callp = copi((Vector) allPopulation.get(rdmCross1));
    muted = crossover(callp, copy);
    System.out.println("cross over Between two Randoms ----------->");
    affiche_resultat(muted);
    allPopulation.add(muted);
   }
}
```

});

The loop :

```
CrossOp.setDaemon(true);

int loop = 1;
long StartTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
for (int i = 0; i < loop; ++i) { 
    loop++;
    if (timevalue < ((System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000) - StartTime)) {
        loop = 0;
     CrossOpb = false;   
    }
CrossOp.start();
}
```

Comment: `Thread#stop()` This method is inherently unsafe.... Many uses of stop should be replaced by code that simply modifies some variable to indicate that the target thread should stop running. The target thread should check this variable regularly, and return from its run method in an orderly fashion if the variable indicates that it is to stop running. For more information, see [Why are Thread.stop, Thread.suspend and Thread.resume Deprecated?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html).

Comment: Don't ever invoke `destroy()` on another thread. It only stops your thread.

Comment: @hexafraction i ve created a `public volatile boolean CrossOpb = true;` to set the Thread as on/off but it won't stop .. any ideas ??

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After reading the whole last night about threads, i have discovered that the solution for my problem was not that hard.
The idea was to edit the condition of the stopping loop inside the thread so we control it by giving it a specific amount of time to run for it and here is my Example :

```
class ProcessorCordm extends Thread {
    int runningtime;
    public ProcessorCordm(int runningtime) {
        this.runningtime = runningtime;
    }
    public void run() {
        int loop = 1;
        long StartTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
        for (int i = 0; i < loop; ++i) {
            int rdmCross2 = (int) (Math.random() * allPopulation.size()); // Crossover 1st vector
            int rdmCross1 = (int) (Math.random() * allPopulation.size());
            Vector muted = new Vector();
            Vector copy = copi((Vector) allPopulation.get(rdmCross2));
            Vector callp = copi((Vector) allPopulation.get(rdmCross1));
            muted = crossover(callp, copy);
            System.out.println("cross over Between two Randoms ----------->");
            affiche_resultat(muted);
            addsolution(muted);
            loop++;
            if (timevalue < ((System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000) - StartTime)) {
                loop = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So if i want to run my **Thread** for **10 seconds**  i only need to :

```
 ProcessorCoG CrossOpg = new ProcessorCoG(10);
```

And fo my case, I have to call many Threads simultaneously working for a specific **TimeValue** so i used the `ExecutorService`Class :

```
            ProcessorCoG CrossOpg = new ProcessorCoG(timevalue);//extends Thread class
            ProcessorCordm CrossOp = new ProcessorCordm(timevalue);//extends Thread class
            ProcessorCordm CrossOp2 = new ProcessorCordm(timevalue);//extends Thread class
            MutateGb MutGb = new MutateGb(timevalue);//extends Thread class
            MutateRdm MutRdm = new MutateRdm(timevalue);//extends Thread class
            MbsRdm MbsR = new MbsRdm(timevalue);//extends Thread class
            ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(6);
            executor.submit(MutGb);
            executor.submit(MutRdm);
            executor.submit(CrossOp);
            executor.submit(CrossOp2);
            executor.submit(CrossOpg);
            executor.submit(MbsR);
```

Answer (score 2):

I already answered to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18221785/how-do-i-kill-a-playloop-when-a-thread-is-killed/18221900#18221900). In that case, it was C#, but the concept is the same.

You **must not** kill threads. Threads must exit on their own will.
Just put a `volatile boolean` variable somewhere, and set it to true/false, when you want your thread to terminate, then, in the thread, replace the `while (true)` with a `while (myVariable == true/false)`.

Anyway, you say:

> Inside the loop, am going to call 5 procedures ant i thought that if i put each procedure in a thread will make the program making more solutions in a same time than calling normal methods.

Well, that's generally false. If the procedures are data-dependent (each of them depends on the results of the previous one), putting them on threads will change nothing. It might be smarter to put iterations in a pipeline, so that you have 5 threads executing steps of successive iterations. I'm not sure if that's possible for genetic algorithms, and anyway you'll have to handle some special case (e.g. a mutation, that alters the population of partially computed iterations).

Comment: Granco i tried that look at my new code .. and still same result .. :(

Comment: Looking at what you did, the thread should now terminate in the very moment you start it (because it starts when `CrossOpb` is already false. How are you checking if it's running or not? (Why you think it's not stopping?)

Comment: CrossOpB needs to be public volatile boolean, not just public boolean.

Comment: @Giulio Franco am checking it with the function `affiche_resultat(muted);` it prints the obtained solution. <br>
i don't know i thought maybe because am using interface ? and i run the loop when i click in a jbutton .. ? am printing the last results in a new jframe but the thread won't stop and keep running and bloke all the following instruction so it bloks the jframe .. and everything

Comment: @James corrected it and gives the same results .. still won't stop !

Comment: @GhassenBellagha what you're saying makes little sense. If the code is running on another thread, by definition, it can't block your frame, because the frame runs on the AWT thread. Also, in the code you posted, I can't see any instruction that says something like "block until the thread has ended". So, the two things shouldn't be able to block each other.

Answer (score 1):

### How to run a `Thread` for a specific amount of time:

Here is the basic approach is to keep calculate how long the `Thread` has run and exit and return the result, which in our case here is details on how long the `Thread` executed.

*NOTE: you must use `System.nanoTime()` as `System.currentTimeMillis()` will just return the same thing every time you call it in the method.*

I use a `Random` number to calculate different lifetimes for each of the `Callables` so that you can see that they don't execute *exactly* for the time specified but they are very very close, and the variance of the delta is pretty consistent, at least on my machine.

Here a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/jarrodhroberson/6576060#file-question18818482-java) of the code below for easier access.

```
package com.stackoverflow.Q18818482;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Question18818482
{
    public static Random RND;

    static
    {
        RND = new Random();
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            final ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
            final List<Future<String>> results = new ArrayList<>(10);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                results.add(es.submit(new TimeSliceTask(RND.nextInt(10), TimeUnit.SECONDS)));
            }
            es.shutdown();
            while(!results.isEmpty())
            {
                final Iterator<Future<String>> i = results.iterator();
                while (i.hasNext())
                {
                    final Future<String> f = i.next();
                    if (f.isDone())
                    {
                        System.out.println(f.get());
                        i.remove();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        catch (ExecutionException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static class TimeSliceTask implements Callable<String>
    {
    private final long timeToLive;
    private final long duration;


    public TimeSliceTask(final long timeToLive, final TimeUnit timeUnit)
    {
        this.timeToLive = System.nanoTime() + timeUnit.toNanos(timeToLive);
        this.duration = timeUnit.toMillis(timeToLive);
    }

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception
    {
        while( timeToLive <= System.nanoTime() )
        {
            // simulate work here
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
        final long end = System.nanoTime();
        return String.format("Finished Elapsed Time = %d, scheduled for %d", TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(timeToLive - end), this.duration );
    }
    }
}
```

### Here is what one runs output looks like

*NOTE: All times are in milliseconds*

```
Finished Elapsed Time = 999, scheduled for 1000
Finished Elapsed Time = 2998, scheduled for 3000
Finished Elapsed Time = 5999, scheduled for 6000
Finished Elapsed Time = 1994, scheduled for 2000
Finished Elapsed Time = 8994, scheduled for 9000
Finished Elapsed Time = 6993, scheduled for 7000
Finished Elapsed Time = 6993, scheduled for 7000
Finished Elapsed Time = 5993, scheduled for 6000
Finished Elapsed Time = 5998, scheduled for 6000
```